# How do I make clang format wrap functions by breaking after commas?

Tags: c++, clang-format

Suppose I have the following function definition:

```cpp
void MyVideoClass::Play(CJNIVideo* pJNIVideo, const char* pFile, float startPos, bool bLooping, int nGLTextureId)
//                                                                      Column Limit Here:        >
```

Based on the column limit above, I expect the last argument to be wrapped and then indented once:

```cpp
void MyVideoClass::Play(CJNIVideo* pJNIVideo, const char* pFile, float startPos, bool bLooping,
   int nGLTextureId)
```

However, what I really get is:

```cpp
void MyVideoClass::Play(
   CJNIVideo* pJNIVideo, const char* pFile, float startPos, bool bLooping, int nGLTextureId)
```

Here is my `.clang-format` (I'm using version 8.0.0 of LLVM):

```
---
Language:        Cpp
AccessModifierOffset: -3
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands:   false
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum:       true
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct:     true
  AfterUnion:      true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true
  IndentBraces:    true
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: true
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit:     100
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: true
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 3
ContinuationIndentWidth: 3
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IncludeBlocks:   Preserve
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '^(<|"(gtest|gmock|isl|json)/)'
    Priority:        3
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        1
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentWidth:     3
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: Inner
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Auto
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 3
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: false
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 2000
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 1
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 100
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerAlignment: Left
ReflowComments:  true
SortIncludes:    true
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        Cpp11
StatementMacros:
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
TabWidth:        3
UseTab:          Never
...
```

How do I modify my configuration to get the desired wrap behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have the correct settings for this:

```
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
```

However, since it doesn't work, it seems you found a clang-format bug.

Comment: This is still an issue with clang-format 10 (Linux Mint 19.3, installed from the official PPA)

Comment: ... as an added bonus, it only happens if the column limit is sufficiently big. I had mine set to 120, but it works properly with 80.